# Jewish significance of being an uncle or aunt?

Tags: sources-mekorot, family-members

Is there any Jewish significance to the relationship between an uncle/aunt and their nephew/niece? Meaning to say, are there any special things (opportunities, responsibilities) about being an uncle/aunt which Torah recognizes? Are there any classical (or contemporary) Torah works which touch upon this?

Comment: Aunt can't marry a nephew. Is that significant?

Comment: Ditto avunculate marriage and honor of an uncle?

Comment: @Oliver required honor of an uncle would be significant. Chinuch responsibilities, or roles as a model of behavior... that type of stuff.

Comment: @Chaim [Avunculate marriage](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62b.19?with=all&lang=bi) isn’t significant?

Comment: Dodato, eshel achi Aviv, in arayot. Dodo in nachalot see 6th chapter in Gemara Yevamot

Comment: "או דודו או בן דודו יגאלנו" - the closest relations have the first responsibilities toward helping/saving their kin in need. The Torah first mentions the uncle.

Comment: @Oliver now that you've provided that source, it is!

Answer (score 2):

Rabbeinu Yonah in Sefer HaYirah 203 [Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51104&st=&pgnum=51&hilite=) and [Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51104&st=&pgnum=52) writes, that there is an obligation to honor your father's brother and your mother's brother.

[See footnote in the Mekor HaYirah who questions the source.]

The Birkei Yosef YD 240/21 brings this from Rabbeinu Yonah and from the Sefer HaChareidim.